# Trouble finding html object for scraper

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm trying to create a dataset from a website. I found the dataset on kaggle and wanted to use the scraper the guy used to get an updated version but I'm having some issues with an error. It's giving me this error:

AttributeError:

```
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

which I understand that means that this line isn't finding the data and has changed in some way (based on what I found from googling this):

```
chart = soup.find("table", class_="chart")
```

I've gone to the page and used ctrl + u to look at the html and find the table/chart something but I've not been able to find what I need. Is there a better way to find this, or can someone direct me to it please, I'd appreciate any help thanks!

I tried to add the text here but it was giving me an error after the except: continue and not accepting any code after that and wouldn't post, so here is the link to the github fork:

https://github.com/Suljin/vgchartzScrape/blob/master/vgchartzfull.py

Here is the kaggle link: https://www.kaggle.com/rush4ratio/video-game-sales-with-ratings/home

Sorry, forgot the url, which would really help ><
http://www.vgchartz.com/gamedb/?page=18&results=1000&name=&platform=&minSales=0.01&publisher=&genre=&sort=GL

Comment: Can you post the website link seems it is from kaggle. And are you aware of  [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html).

Comment: No, I've never done this before and only just learning Python so I was hoping to just use the same scraper that the guy had used when he made the dataset a few years ago. If I have to I'll see if I can use pandas.read_html but i'd rather avoid it (I'm on a time constraint) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the link and then based on html latest html tags, I updated the code as below and it should work. Although the column names has changed so you can change it accordingly.

Here is the updated code (Python 3):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import pandas as pd

pages = 18
rec_count = 0
rank = []
gname = []
platform = []
year = []
genre = []
publisher = []
sales_na = []
sales_eu = []
sales_jp = []
sales_ot = []
sales_gl = []

urlhead = 'http://www.vgchartz.com/gamedb/?page='
urltail = '&results=1000&name=&platform=&minSales=0.01&publisher=&genre=&sort=GL'

for page in range(1, pages):
    surl = urlhead + str(page) + urltail
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(surl).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, features="lxml")
    print(page)
    chart = soup.find('div', id='generalBody').find('table')
    for row in chart.find_all('tr')[3:]:
        try:
            col = row.find_all('td')

            # extract data into column data
            column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
            column_2 = col[1].find('img')['alt'].strip()
            column_3 = col[2].find('a').string.strip()
            column_4 = col[3].find('img')['alt'].strip()
            column_5 = col[4].string.strip()
            column_6 = col[5].string.strip()
            column_7 = col[6].string.strip()
            column_8 = col[7].string.strip()
            column_9 = col[8].string.strip()
            column_10 = col[9].string.strip()
            column_11 = col[10].string.strip()

            # Add Data to columns
            # Adding data only if able to read all of the columns
            rank.append(column_1)
            gname.append(column_2)
            platform.append(column_3)
            year.append(column_4)
            genre.append(column_5)
            publisher.append(column_6)
            sales_na.append(column_7)
            sales_eu.append(column_8)
            sales_jp.append(column_9)
            sales_ot.append(column_10)
            sales_gl.append(column_11)

            rec_count += 1

        except:
            print('Got Exception')
            continue

columns = {'Rank': rank, 'Name': gname, 'Platform': platform, 'Year': year, 'Genre': genre, 'Publisher': publisher,
           'NA_Sales': sales_na, 'EU_Sales': sales_eu, 'JP_Sales': sales_jp, 'Other_Sales': sales_ot,
           'Global_Sales': sales_gl}

print (rec_count)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
print(df)
df = df[['Rank', 'Name', 'Platform', 'Year', 'Genre', 'Publisher', 'NA_Sales', 'EU_Sales', 'JP_Sales', 'Other_Sales',
         'Global_Sales']]
del df.index.name
df.to_csv("vgsales.csv", sep=",", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks @nandneo! I see what you changed and wasn't even close to that so appreciate it! I ran what you gave me and I get several lines such as:
 File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)"  

At the end it says "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Rate"

Which I think means I'm requesting from the url too frequently?

Answer (score 0):

This site explicitly deny scrapping. Terms of use states:

'Unauthorized access to our sites is a breach of these Terms and a violation of the law. You agree not to access our sites by any means other than through the interface that is provided by VGChartz Ltd for use in accessing our sites. You agree not to use any automated means, including, without limitation, agents, robots, scripts, or spiders, to access, monitor, or copy any part of our sites, except those automated means that we have approved in advance and in writing.' - http://www.vgchartz.com/terms-of-use.php

Did you ask permission to scrap their data?